# string into mutable array objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string

I am trying to create a NSMutableArray out of a NSString. It shouldn't be separated by anything. So if the string is `@"0123"` the array should be `{@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", nil}`. But if I use the code bellow it creates an array like `{@"0123", nil}`. In the code bellow I also convert a regular array to a mutable array, because I don't know how to do it directly..

```
NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@""]];
```

Comment: @H2CO3: I remember few days back, we both solved similar question..

Comment: @AnoopVaidya If you look closely, the dupe is a question from early 2012. (Well, the question what I think you're talking about is a bit different, there the emphasis was on characters, here it's the array that matters... whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSInteger i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [string characterAtIndex:i]]];
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you actually have to write code.

Comment: @HotLicks: I dint get you....

Comment: This code fails if the string has any Unicode characters of \U10000 or greater. This includes Emoji characters and many others.

Comment: As per OP's example... string=@"01234" .

Comment: I was pointing out a potential pitfall in the answer. This way people can make an informed decision about whether the answer fits their needs or not.

Comment: @rmaddy: should i use `substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,1)` ?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya No, that has the same problem. See the answers in the 2nd duplicate question.